# How do I get the GCP Cloud Function actual called URL, including query parameters (Python runtime)

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In a GCP Cloud Function using the Python environment, I'd like to get the entire actual http request URL.  Normally, Flask exposes this via `request.url`.  However, in the cloud function environment, the request object appears to be manipulated by GCP so that `request.url` does not provide the actual full URL, with query parameters.  For instance, if I POST to my function at:

`https://us-east1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/func-name?test=true`

the value of `request.url` is (note the scheme):

`http://us-east1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net?test=true`

I found nothing in the documentation that would explain this.  It seems that the actual function name is available as an environment variable (`FUNCTION_NAME`), but I'd have to re-assemble the URL using this, including  guessing/hoping the scheme was HTTPs, and it seems like an ugly way to go about it.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this seems like a bug with Cloud Functions. I've filed an issue accordingly, will update when I have more information for you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DustinIngram , can you please add a link, pointing to the public issue tracker entry you've filed? And also, could you put your comment as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: @alextru Unfortunately there is no link, it's an internal tracker, but feel free to file an external issue as well.

Comment: A public issue has been filed and can be followed for updates here : https://issuetracker.google.com/130389805